# Tomcat's request.getParameter() translates %<hex> to unicode replacement character

Tags: tomcat, servlets, character-encoding

This is an old web application, that does not work correctly with the current Tomcat. Perhaps it did work with the ancient one, I have no idea.

Anyway, there is a malfunctioning `request.getParameter("query")` within a servlet's `doGet()`, where `request.toString()` turns out to be as follows:

```
uri: /library/indextable
method: GET
QueryString: mode=1&type=7&query=%B3omozik
Parameters:
    Name: mode  Value: 1
    Name: type  Value: 7
    Name: query Value: �omozik
Headers:
    Name: host  Value: localhost:8084
    Name: user-agent    Value: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
    Name: accept    Value: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Name: accept-language   Value: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Name: accept-encoding   Value: gzip, deflate
    Name: referer   Value: http://localhost:8084/library/indextable?mode=1&type=7
    Name: cookie    Value: JSESSIONID=6FECF93B858C3AE3318C359DEE4C9EC5
    Name: connection    Value: keep-alive
```

The character � is in fact \ufffd, Unicode's replacement character. For whatever reason, URL's %B3 (ISO-8859-2's ł) is translated into it. The web page containing the respective GET form has a tag

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2">`

Tomcat is run with the locale `pl_PL.ISO8859-2`.

The method `request.setCharacterEncoding()` returns null, unless
`request.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-2")` or `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` is specified at the beginning of `doGet()`, but none of these two help.

**How can I make the request object translate hex--notated ISO 8859-2 characters into Unicode characters (e.g. %B3 to ł)?** It is a legacy code, it just needs to work with possibly minimal fixes, no best practices and elegance needed.

Comment: That is exactly what is supposed to happen. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I added a question in bold.

Comment: Try to add `URIEncoding="ISO-8859-2"` attribute to the HTTP `<Connector>` in your `server.xml`.

Comment: Thanks Jozef, but it does not seem to help.